# Efficient merge-product-sum with Pandas

Tags: pandas, merge, sum, sparse-matrix

Consider two dataframes where the `Z` column contains integers (although we can also think of it as just containing values from a discrete set),

`df_1`:

```
A | B | Z | PROB
--+---+---+-----
. | . | . |  .
. | . | . |  .
. | . | . |  .
```

and

`df_2`:

```
C | D | Z | PROB
--+---+---+-----
. | . | . |  .
. | . | . |  .
. | . | . |  .
```

Want I am doing currently is merging on `Z`,

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Z'])
```

to get

`df`:

```
A | B | C | D | Z | PROB_x | PROB_y
--+---+---+---+---+--------+-------
. | . | . | . | . |    .   |    .
. | . | . | . | . |    .   |    .
. | . | . | . | . |    .   |    .
```

Then multiplying the probability columns

```
df['PROB'] = df['PROB_x']*df['PROB_y']
```

attempting to drop the old probability columns (although this causes my computer to crash for larger sized problems).

```
df.drop(['PROB_x', 'PROB_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and finally group summing to get probabilities for each `(A, B), (C, D)` combination

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).sum()
```

Now if we look at our initial problem we can see it actually looks like a sparse 'matrix x matrix' problem. Let `X` be some mapping of `(A,B)` pairs to integers and `Y` be some mapping of `(C,D)` pairs to integers.

Then the transformed `df_1` becomes

`df_1_mapped`:

```
X | Z | PROB
--+---+-----
. | . |  .
. | . |  .
. | . |  .
```

and `df_2` becomes

`df_2_mapped`:

```
Y | Z | PROB
--+---+-----
. | . |  .
. | . |  .
. | . |  .
```

both now in sparse COO format. What we actually want is

```
df_1_mapped * df_2_mapped.T
```

a sparse matrix multiplication which I believe can be done more efficiently than the merge-product-sum (maybe converting sparse format first) that I am doing. This gives

```
X | Y | PROB
--+---+-----
. | . |  .
. | . |  .
. | . |  .
```

where `.T` represents transpose.

Hence I feel there must be a more efficient way of doing what I want than

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Z'])
df['PROB'] = df['PROB_x']*df['PROB_y']
df.drop(['PROB_x', 'PROB_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).sum()
```

My question is then, is this more efficient way implemented in Pandas and how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A minor suggestion which might reduce maximum memory used.  Not tested as no example data but the idea is just to reuse a column then drop one rather than create a new one then drop two.  Does that work?

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Z'],suffixes=('','_y'))
df['PROB'] = df['PROB']*df['PROB_y']
df.drop(['PROB_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by converting the Pandas dataframes to sparse Scipy matrices and it is far quicker and less memory intensive to do it this way. See this repository for the code to do it: https://github.com/rwolst/pandas-merge-product-sum.

Note however I would prefer a strict Pandas solution to this so will not accept this answer, although it may be useful to others.